# Plone 3.3.5: How to export weblogentry to XML/CSV (csvreplicata)

Tags: plone, export-to-csv

I'm running plone 3.3.5
I use Quills for blogging and need to export the entries to either XML of CSV.
I tried with the standard export to xml in zope, but this is not working.
So now I want to use products.csvreplicata, installation was succesfull, but I don't know how to use is.

Answer (score 0):

ZMI export in XML is broken and it's however a very low level export, unreadable by human (do not use it).

CVSReplicata is an add-on targeted for developers, not for final users that want to export. It mean you must write some code (as the documentation says: see interfaces and adapters).